# convert /proc/1/environ to variables script

Tags: linux, awk, cat, proc, tr

Environment: 
Old version of systemd is running in a container. By default systemd started services do not get the environment variables of the container, because systemd deletes them for new started processes. Newer versions allow to pass variables via systemd Directives, but this is not feasible here to use a newer version.

I have to use some of the passed environment variables for a script and initially this was easy i thought, this small script already does 90% of the job

```
$ cat /proc/1/environ |tr '\0' '\n' 
HOME=/
TERM=linux
```

But now I do have environment variables which contain "\n"  , which result in something like that

```
VAR=totally
screwed
up
```

or even contain = or other special utf8 chars, etc.

Is there any clever why to get this content properly in to a script which just assigns the values to variables?

In the end it should probably result in something like this.

```
VAR="totally\nscrewed\up"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My /proc/1/environ file has not any strange characters inside, so i copied this file and i broke some entries to come close to your situation.

This one should work ok to split the file on an array based on the null separator:

```
$ while IFS= read -r -d '' line ; do vars+=("$line");done <file;declare -p vars
```

By using declare -p we can check the data present in the array.

Just for the record, also the readarray method (without the need to use a while loop) seems to work ok:

```
IFS= readarray -t -d '' vars <file
```

Comment: seems not work for me (TM).   it still creates the "screwed" "up" as separate lines in the vars array  ([0]=VARS=totally"  [1]="screwed"  [2]="up")

Comment: @Mandragor OK, yes not working. Try this trick - this should work:  `readarray -t vars2 < <(cat file4 |tr -d '\n' |tr '\0' '\n')`. Actually we remove any new line from the initial file and then we convert null bytes to new lines. We can't miss it like this

Comment: hmm, i need the '\n' later on. so basically it must keep it in as said above something like  VAR="totally\nscrewed\nup"  helps for the \n problem. so if the string contains "  also needs to be escaped ... etc

Comment: @Mandragor Good point. With this solution should work ok. We cut the fields stricly based on the null character : `while IFS= read -r -d '' line ; do vars2+=("$line");done <file3;declare -p vars2`

Comment: yes, it seems to solve it (for my problems i have :))   . Can you please edit your answer so that i can rate it as solution.

Comment: @Mandragor Done

Comment: @Mandragor Also this solution seems to work witout while loop : `IFS= readarray -t -d '' vars2 <file3;declare -p vars2`
Can you test it since you have such a strange file? Would be interesting to know if works ok.

Comment: no. doesn't work '-d invalid option'  . Removing it does also not lead to success

Comment: @Mandragor We can not remove it, is the delimiter. Works fine in my Debian even (with IFS= readarray -t -d '' array <file). Mind the space after -d and before ''

Comment: Is there a way this can work in sh?  Currently I get an error of `Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`